# bash Alt-f prints international 'ash' character instead of doing forward-word

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-layout

I recently switched to `bash` from `csh`.
I normally use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> for forward-word on the command line.

Since I've switched to bash it prints `æ` instead.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> also shows `æ`.

```
echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Comment: The answer to this may depend on what terminal emulator you're using, and whether it's configured to use the Alt key as the emacs Meta key. It might also depend on whether anything in your setup is messing with bash's command-line editing support. Do other emacs-isms for moving the cursor work? If not, something in your setup may be telling bash to use its vi-style editing mode.

Comment: Other emacs-isms do work.  All of the Ctl based commands work as they did in csh.  ctl-a moves to the beginning of the line, etc.

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess I should have been more clear. It would help to know which GUI app you're using as a terminal emulator, not just what target terminal it's trying to emulate. Also check your settings/preferences for your emulator app and see what it says about the emacs Meta key.

Comment: I use xterm.  I just tried rxvt and that one work how I want.  I have no idea what's different.

Comment: uxterm also works like I want